# zoom the Image Element in QML. without using QImage::scaled(), QPixmap::scaled().

Tags: image, qt, qml

I am trying to implement zoom in / out of a image using Image Element in QML.
I want the Pixel scale to be modified if i double click / pinch zoom.

How can i implement this without using  QImage::scaled(), QPixmap::scaled(). 
Basically i dont want to involve Qt logic into my application.

I want Similar effect to hat is happening in the following tutorial
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/widgets-imageviewer.html

But without Qt Logic in the app.

Answer (score 1):

i know it's not the best answer but i cannot write a comment (i got less then 50 reps...) but zooming in/out qml is easy using  [PinchArea](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-pincharea.html) if you add a MouseArea you can also use onClicked or onDoubleClicked.... there is a useful example for pinch to zoom [here(qt.git)](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/systemtests/source/72f6a9ee7ca58fc0a9687fe29cd42f412aec6acf%3aQt/examples/declarative/pincharea/pincharea.qml).
The ImageViewer example you posted got features like print save and so on, and you don't want to use "qt Logic", so i think you will need to use "qt Logic". I would wirte one class for each feature and implement it where i need it. 
first of all [i think this could help you(Extending QML Functionalities using C++).](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-extending.html)
Here a (not tested) example for saveing and reading a file:

fileio.h

```
#ifndef FILEIO_H
#define FILEIO_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>
class FileIO : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
Q_PROPERTY(QString source
           READ source
           WRITE setSource
           NOTIFY sourceChanged)
explicit FileIO(QObject *parent = 0);


Q_INVOKABLE QString source();
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant read();
Q_INVOKABLE bool write(const QVariant& data);

public slots:
void setSource(const QString& source) ;

signals:
void sourceChanged(const QString& source);
void error(const QString& msg);

private:
QString mSource;
};

#endif // FILEIO_H
```

and fileio.cpp

```
#include "fileio.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

FileIO::FileIO(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent){
}

QString FileIO::source(){
return mSource;
}

QVariant FileIO::read()
{
if (mSource.isEmpty()){
    emit error("source is empty");
    return QVariant();
}

QFile file(mSource);
QVariant fileContent; // i dont know if you can use QImage but i think you cann't
if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ) {
    QDataStream t( &file );
    fileContent << t //you may have to reimplement "<<" operator
    file.close();
} else {
    emit error("Unable to open the file");
    return QVariant();
}
return fileContent;
}.....
```

and register that in main.cpp like

```
qmlRegisterType<FileIO, 1>("FileIO", 1, 0, "FileIO");
```

so you can import it in your qml like

```
import FileIO 1.0
Rectangle{
id: someId
...
FileIO{
id: yourAccessToYourFileIOclass
}
}
```

i've not tested that code yet, i hope it helps.

for better answers post what you want to do exacly save, print , any filters....

p.s. I also would create a model in qt and bring it to qml...

greez Matthias